# Android what is the benefit of a service over a regular class?

Tags: android, service

I have a bluetooth service that I have been using in my app, but I am just wondering what benefits do I get by using a service to handle all the bluetooth stuff over just creating a `bluetoothManager` class? Services seem a little complicated with all this `bind()` stuff. The only benefit I can see from having a service is if you wanted to open your service for other apps to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary role of a service is to help keep your process around a bit longer while you are in the background. Lacking a service, Android may terminate your process very quickly when you are no longer in the foreground.

This is covered as part of [the documentation on processes and their lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes).

There are other reasons to use services, such as for IPC as you suggest.

> Services seem a little complicated with all this bind() stuff

Note that services do not have to use the binding pattern, though that is certainly an option.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts: Um, just call `startService()` to start up the service. Pass data to the service in the `Intent`.